# how can I exclude files from being taked to the account by PHPUnit in coverage

Tags: phpunit, codecov

I have a Codecov that listens to the test suites, let's for example say we have only an integration tests suit, the config will look something like this:
codecov.yaml

```
coverage:
  status:
    project:
      default:
        target: 50%
        threshold: 0%
        base: auto    
        if_no_uploads: error  
        if_not_found: success
      integration:
        target: 75%
        threshold: 0%  
        base: auto    
        if_no_uploads: error 
        if_not_found: success 
        flags:
          - integration
```

let's say I have a lot of files called `Resouser.php` in different directories under `/src/App/Ui/` that hold only open API documentation configs but not actual PHP code, so I want to exclude them from coverage.

If I understand correctly it needs to be done in the `<coverage>` section of phpunit.xml, right? So I did like this:

```
  <coverage cacheDirectory="var/phpunit/coverage/.phpunit.cache">
    <exclude>
      <directory suffix="Resource.php">./src/App/Ui/</directory>
    </exclude>
    <report>
      <clover outputFile="var/phpunit/coverage/clover.xml"/>
      <crap4j outputFile="var/phpunit/coverage/crap4j.xml"/>
      <html outputDirectory="var/phpunit/coverage"/>
      <xml outputDirectory="var/phpunit/coverage"/>
      <text outputFile="php://stdout" showUncoveredFiles="true"/>
    </report>
```

a told I wanted to exclude all the files in the directory `./src/App/Ui/` with the suffix `EndpointResource.php` and nothing changes, the coverage percentage is the same, and the amount of covered vs total files is still the same

```
Code Coverage Report:        
  2024-01-16 14:54:19        
                             
 Summary:                    
  Classes: 56.07% (134/239)
```

as it was before I added `exclude` tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the following annotation on top of your classes/methods to be ignored it should work fine. Might be a bit more work than excluding a whole directory at once but it will work.

```
/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
```